# Hide / Unhide Cloned form elements in jQuery. How?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-events

I can find numerous examples of Hiding and unhiding form elements in jQuery.  I can also find numerous examples of cloning form elements in jQuery.  But is there a way to hide/unhide cloned form elements in jQuery?

For example, lets say I have 3 product categories (selectable from a dropdown box).  Each of these product categories has its own form elements associated with it.  I want to allow the user to be able to inquire about 1 or all of the product categories multiple times.

For example, lets say a user selects a product category. The form elements associated with the product category they selected will unhide.  User can input into those form elements and submit the form...or they have the option to select again from the same or another product category and fill out the form elements associated with their second selection, third selection, etc. etc.

Does this make sense?

Help?!

An absolute newbie

Comment: Could you maybe show some mark-up, to give us a clue what you're working with?

Comment: Did either of the posted answers help you at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what elements are cloned.  Perhaps you can elaborate on that.

However, if you can assign a "class" to any elements that share functionality (e.g. are supposed to be hidden at the same), you can hide all of those elements that have that class.  Maybe the select option has class="product_cat_1", and there are 3 divs that have class="product_cat_1" as well.. then you could use jquery to hide all div's with class="product_cat_1"

---

EDIT:
One trick I've used for your situation is to wrap each block of cloned elements in a container div, with a unique id:

```
<div id="new_item_1">
    <select class="productcat1" name="productcat1[]">...</select> 
</div>
```

Then with jQuery when you clone the fields, you can add all your javascript relative to that parent container:

```
$('#new_item_1 .productcat1').select(...);
```

Comment: The elements to be cloned would be the first selection dropdown box, and the form elements (i.e. text inputs, dropdowns, etc.) that go along with all the product categories.  Each product category has its own combination / spread of form elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the cloned form elements in a `fieldset`, and include the `remove` button (or link, or whatever) inside that same fieldset, you can call:

```
$('.hideButtonClass').live('click',
function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wQDSX/1/)

Comment: Okay...this is the form I am trying to work on. www.pentco.com/test.php.  I am trying to get it so that the first choice in the dropdown - only the first box appears.  Second choice - second box, third choice - third box.  When you add an item, I just need the initial selection box to be shown.  Then the user can select another product category, and fill in the form elements associated with their selection...so they might pick the second selection and the second box would appear.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.  So I used your fieldset suggestion.  However I have two problems.  First, is the cloned product category selection dropdown will not change the form elements when you go to select a category.  It only does for the original product category dropdown.  Second, is there a way to get it so that the remove button only appears for cloned elements, not the original one?  And third, clone elements have numbers that appear in the text inputs.  Is there a way to have them blank?  Please go back to pentco.com/test.php